# Intermittent Disconnection to DB on SAN. Event ID 17053 and 9001

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am getting some strange issues with our MS SQL 2008 database where intermittently we lose connection to the db for 10+ seconds or so.  The db is stored on a SAN over fiber.  The latest event log error I get is "LogWriter: Operating System error 1 (incorrect function) encountered with an event ID of 17053.  Following that error is event ID 9001 about log for database is not available.  I would then see a message stating recovery is completed for database in 12 seconds.  Not sure how to approach this and any help or guidance would be much appreciated.  Running MS SQL 2008 on Windows 2008 SP1.

Comment: Do you have a SAN specialist on staff or on call? They'd probably need to review the SAN logs/config.

Answer (score 2):

You need to either have a SAN admin look at the system of bring a consultant in to look at it.  (Yes I'm a [SAN consultant](http://mrdenny.com), no that's not why I'm saying this.)

Comment: So you all think this error is related to issue accessing the SAN?

Comment: Yep, sure do. Pretty much any time you see an Operating System error it isn't going to be a SQL Server problem.

Comment: Agree with Denny, 99% likely to be connectivity to the SAN. When you call the SAN guy, remind him to bring replacement cables and just in case an HBA. More than likely someone nudged/tripped over/damaged a cable.

Comment: OK, thanks everyone for the advice and suggestion.  You all are very supportive.